# Disable KWallet password request in Arch Plasma 5

Tags: arch-linux, plasma, kwallet

KWallet requests a password on startup. I want to get rid of this but I have found no way to disable it and also cannot remove KWallet itself:

```
# sudo pacman -R kwallet
checking dependencies...
error: failed to prepare transaction (could not satisfy dependencies)
:: kio: requires kwallet
```

How can I stop this password prompt from appearing each time I log in? I am using Arch Linux and Plasma 5.

Answer (score 13):

You can

- remove the password from the wallet. Start the kwalletmanager and then click on »change password«.
- disable the wallet. Start the kwalletmanager and go to settings / configure wallet. Uncheck the box »Enable the KDE wallet subsystem«.

Comment: Remove the password worked for me in plasma 5 ( disable wallet not )

Comment: When I run `kwalletmanager5` on kubuntu 16.04, it just exits 0 without doing anything.

Answer (score 5):

[You can create or edit `~/.config/kwalletrc` with the following content:](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/KDE_Wallet#Disable_KWallet)

```
[Wallet]
Enabled=false
```

This has the advantage of not requiring to install `kwalletmanager` just to disable it.

Comment: You may also need to add `Prompt on Open=false` to the same section of this file. It will disable kwallet pop-up window every time a KDE application wants to deal with passwords.

Comment: In my experience `Enabled=false` was enough for that too, but of course it does not cost much to also add your line.

Comment: The problem with this is you dont get your password stored. So its equally anoying. you dont type the kwallet password pbut you get to type other passwords over and over again.

Comment: @jstuartmilne Well the question was about disabling kwallet, not using it without password.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo pacman -Rdd kwallet
```

Worked for me

Comment: Why do you think that worked? (A little explanation in answers is always nice)

Comment: This is not a good idea, since you are actually telling pacman to not take dependencies into account. This might lead to crashes (some binaries depend on libs provided by this package), and also means the package will be re-installed anyway on any further depending program install or update.